# javascript array push values in TinyMCE editor plugin

Tags: javascript, arrays, tinymce

I'm working on a plugin for TinyMCE editor. The idea is very simple, basically the user can insert a product link from a dropdown selecter where a custom class and a link to the page of the product are automatically added.

I get data from an array like this one:

```
function products_list() {
    return array(
        array('product-tag-1' => 'Product 1', 'https://website.com/product1-page'),
        array('product-tag-3' => 'Product 2', 'https://website.com/product2-page'),
        array('product-tag-3' => 'Product 2', 'https://website.com/product3-page'),
    );
}
```

and here is the plugin code:

```
(function() {
    
    var _products_list = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < products_list.length; i++){
        var product = _products_list[i];
        _products_list.push({ product: Object.values(product)[1], url: Object.values(product)[0], tag: Object.keys(product)[1]});
        console.info(_products_list);
    }
    
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('product_link', function( editor, url ) {
        editor.addButton( 'product_link', {
            text: 'Product Link',
            icon: false,
            onclick: function() {
                editor.windowManager.open( {
                    title: 'Select a  Product',
                    body: [{
                        type: 'listbox',
                        name: 'productSelect',
                        values: _products_list,
                        onPostRender: function( ){
                            productSelect = this;
                        }
                    },
                    {type: 'textbox', name: 'linkText', label: 'anchor text'}
                    
                    ],
                    onsubmit: function( e ) {
              
                            link = editor.insertContent('<a href="' + productSelect.url() +  '" target="_blank" class="textualLink_'+ productSelect.tag() + '">' + e.data.linkText + '</a>');       
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

But when I select something it returns this error in console : 'Uncaught Typerror: productSelect.url is not a function'.
Any hint?

Tried to debug code but nothing worked.

Comment: Tried, it returns a different error: 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')"

Comment: Try with this lines of code for checking variable has value or not.
`var selectedProduct = productSelect.value();
if (selectedProduct) {
    link = editor.insertContent('<a href="' + selectedProduct.url +  '" target="_blank" class="textualLink_'+ selectedProduct.tag + '">' + e.data.linkText + '</a>');
} else {
    console.error("Selected product is undefined");
}`

Comment: Yep, it returns: "Selected product is undefined"